# Android Changing Text of TextView on Button click not working

Tags: android, textview, android-button

As the title shows, I'm trying to make a button in my Android app to change a TextView but it ain't working properly... Here's the code, I hope you guys see what's going wrong. FYI, I'm using NetBeans with the Android 2.3.3 emulator connected as I will be running on my phone (2.3.6) later.

Main java:

```
public class Rooster extends Activity
{
    private Button buttonSearch;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.buttonSearch = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
        this.buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView textRooster = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textRooster); 
                textRooster.setText("some text"); 
            }
        });
    }
```

Well here is my main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="42px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editSearch"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="37px"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Zoekopdracht" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSearch"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="37px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Zoek" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="39px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChangeWijzigingen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="37px"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Zet wijzigingen aan" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="12" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textRooster"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Geen rooster opgezocht" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "It ain't working properly"..In what way exactly? Post your logcat content as well.

Comment: There isn't any problem in your code

Comment: Kazekage Gaara, it is just not doing anything if I click the button! Logcat will be posted later.

Comment: I just test your code and it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the button that you think your clicking is actually getting drawn over. try changing

```
    this.buttonSearch = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
```

to

```
    this.buttonSearch = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonChangeWijzigingen);
```

It doesnt actually fix the problem but just makes more clear what the issue is.

Comment: Hi! At first, thanks for your reply. What do you mean by drawn over? I changed it but that doesn't change the situation.

Comment: Sometimes portions or entire components can get drawn over (one component put on top of another one) if you dont set your xml layout up right.  I had this problem alot when i first started with android.